# Emulator says device does not support the minimum SDK level but it should

Tags: xamarin.android, android-emulator

For some reason today I am no longer able to deploy my Xamarin.Forms app to any android emulators. The emulators were working previously. The error I am seeing in the deployment pad is

```
"Mono.AndroidTools.SdkNotSupportedException: The device does not support the minimum SDK level specified in the manifest".
```

It seems the answer to this is usually that the manifest is just not matching the SDK version of the emulator, however I've checked and I have it set to a minimum of 26 and target of 28. The emulators are on version 27. I tried setting both min/target to 27 as well, but same result.

I have a few theories as to what change may have happened.

1. I recently began preparing the app for google play and I added a package name, where I didn't have one before.
2. I changed the version number to 2 from 1. Also the version name is 2.
3. Updating visual studio (mac)

Any ideas what else I should check?

Comment: Hi,Before version it works ?Just updated Visual studio for mac, then it not works.Is this phenomenon.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it was an update that caused the issue or if it's something else. It could have been related to something else I did preparing the build for release. I have now also tried removing all my emulator images and making a new one, but it's the same result. Also I made a new project and that one is able to deploy, so it must be something local to this project that got messed up. I'm not sure what else to check though.

Comment: Ok so I just changed from Release to Debug (I had a secondary build mode called debug 2 and went back to the original debug). I'm still not clear on what is different in the two build settings, but it is working now. If I can figure out what changed I will post back incase it can help someone else!

Comment: Great, If know the reason, share here :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else hits this issue, it was caused by a blank  inside my Debug|Android configuration block in my csproj. It was created that way using the previous VS Mac IDE.

There is another AndroidManifest element inside my main PropertyGroup, so deleting the blank one (or adding the path to AndroidManifest.xml here) makes the initial error go away.

For additional details, refer to [this solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153294/mono-androidtools-sdknotsupportedexception-when-trying-to-deploy-to-emulator)

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp Isn't "essential content of the link which answers the question" already included in the post?

Comment: It would be nice if the author of this answer could add a code fix example, like in the referred blog. Links always get broken, it is just a matter of time.